# App Engine: different app.yaml files based on environment

Tags: google-app-engine, environment-variables, development-environment

I am currently migrating an application to Google App Engine that relies on environment variables for various external connections.  It looks like the app.yaml file is where I should setup these configurations however how do I manage different environments (development, testing, staging, production) where these variables may be different?

Is the easiest solution just to create a branch for each of these environments with just a different app.yaml file?

Comment: Perhaps better to have different files, e.g. dev.yaml staging.yaml and so on. Then you can run the dev_server with those files explicitly and when you deploy it'll always use app.yaml.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood is there a command to run with a specific config file?  I didn't see that in the documentation.

Comment: you can just say dev_appserver somefile.yaml and it'll use it. very handy. but only locally, not prod afaik.

Comment: Have you looked at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig ? You could switch on appid for different settings.

Comment: You can now do `gcloud app deploy --appyaml=...`

Answer (score 10):

`app.yaml` can **set** environment variables for the rest of the application, but it has no way to **check** them and do different things depending on their incoming values.  Thus, you do need to present different `app.yaml` files to whatever deployment procedure you're using.

As for the best way to prepare the right `app.yaml` as a preliminary step to GAE deployment, that's a subtler devops problem.  Branches in your git or hg or whatever, as you mention, would work, but personally (maybe just bad luck?-) I've often found that the simpler my structure, the better, and branches intended to be long-lived (as opposed to temporary deviation intended to be soon merged back into the trunk) have given me the worse headaches.

So, were it up to me, I'd have a `preapp.yaml` template (maybe jinja2, whatever) with the needed if/else logic, and prepare the right `app.yaml` from it, as the very first step of any deployment, with a simple Python script.

Pretty much the kind of architecture used (for all kind of configuration files, and thus with more inevitable complications) for the currently-beta `gcloud preview deployment-manager`, see https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/ , so of course I could be biased towards the approach (but as I mentioned my bias comes essentially from previous bad deployment experiences:-).

Comment: I would like to understand a bit better how that could work in practice - maybe, since the app.yaml needs to be in the same folder as the service, multiple files could be generated (such as app_dev.yaml, app_testing.yaml), and then you would invoke gcloud app deploy which the respective file as argument? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue for the same reason. I ended up creating aliases for each dev, and prod:

```
alias dev-deploy='cat dev.yaml > app.yaml; gcloud app deploy dev.yaml; rm app.yaml'
alias prod-deploy='cat prod.yaml > app.yaml; gcloud app deploy; rm app.yaml'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for this that would work with a CD pipeline. I use Build Triggers on my git repositories. Using these, I can template the branch name I'm launching from into my cloudbuild.yaml file. My first build step is then to generate app.yaml from a shell script using the branch_name as a conditional value.

```
# cloudbuild.yaml
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', 'app.yaml.sh', '$BRANCH_NAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `gcloud app deploy --help` it says you can pass it a path to the `.yaml` that you'd like to use for deployment:

```sh
EXAMPLES
    To deploy a single service, run:

        $ gcloud app deploy ~/my_app/app.yaml
```

So say you have a `qa, uat, and prod` environments that you want to deploy to.  You could easily create files `app.[env].yaml` for each, and then just pass in the file path that you want to target based on some env variable or something in your CI/CD pipeline.

[https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#:~:text=POSITIONAL%20ARGUMENTS,in%20the%20DEPLOYABLE](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#:%7E:text=POSITIONAL%20ARGUMENTS,in%20the%20DEPLOYABLE).