# Google Cloud App Engine app.yaml for multiple environments

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I currently have my app up and running, the `app.yaml` and `dispatch.yaml` are in the root of the application and I deploy through Google Cloud CLI.

This works well for the moment, though as I move to having a `dev`, `staging` and `prod` environment I can see that it's no longer viable.

The main issue I see is that I have to edit the variables in the `app.yaml` file so they are appropriate for environment (for example I use `env_variables` to store mysql credentials...).

I can't find anything in the docs that points to the correct way to manage this, any ideas?

Also... When deploying from a GIT repo it seems that the `app.yaml` needs to be in the repo, is this correct? It doesn't seem right to me... There must be a better way!

Comment: Unfortunately no, and I share your frustration having used GAE for several years.  Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28283512/3103979

Comment: @Dan damn, I hope they sort this out.

Comment: check out E.'s comment below.  i'm now using something like: 

    `gcloud config configurations activate <ENVIRONMENT>`
    `gcloud app deploy app_<ENVIRONMENT>.yaml --version <VERSION>`

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/managing-configurations https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: @Dan this looks like an interesting solution. How does it work, does `gcloud` somehow auto-generate a separate `app_<ENVIRONMENT>.yaml` file for each dev, staging & prod environments? If so, how does it know what values of each environment var to pass into the file? I'm thinking about a case, say, where you have a 'HOST' and 'PORT' vars for each env and how it would set them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: assuming you use a different application to implement each environment, not different services/module of the same application, which IMHO would be an unnecessary complication. See [How to deploy one app engine app to multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395271/how-to-deploy-one-app-engine-app-to-multiple-projects)

Personally I use a different git branch for each environment.

Granted I only have 2 environments: a development/staging one and the production one, but the same principle applies:

The branch structure reflects the flow through environments:

- the `master` branch is used for the `dev` environment
- the `staging` branch is pulled off the `master` branch
- the `production` branch is pulled off the `staging` branch

To propagate code changes from one environment to another you'd merge the respective child branch to the newer parent branch version (which contains the changes you want to pick up) and deploy the merged child branch code to the corresponding environment.

Each branch has its own version of the `app.yaml` file. You'll have to keep an eye on conflicts in this file which may pop up whenever changes to it are propagated from one branch to another.

See also [Environment Specific Variables In Google App Engine Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106533/environment-specific-varables-in-google-app-engine-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) (and maybe its linked/related posts).

Comment: I am using different projects so this will work well until Google have come up with a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a configuration file or datastore settings to keep track of this environment information. [At minute 26 in this talk](https://youtu.be/Dc4PHFxo-sA) I give some examples of how to customize your environment without needing different `app.yaml` files.

[`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) also accepts a list of yaml files on the command line, with the default being `app.yaml`.