# Configuring different versions of the same service differently in GAE Standard

Tags: java, google-app-engine, configuration-files

Configuring different versions of the same service differently in GAE Standard

I deploy multiple versions of the same service and want them to be configured differently.  For example, the `test` version of a service should run on lower-spec instances (& no idle instances) than the `prod` version of the same service.

Since both deployments share the same `appengine-web.xml`, how do I maintain & use different versions of this configuration file?

On an earlier project I had resorted to having separate `appengine-web.xml.test` and `appengine-web.xml.prod` versions in Git (`appengine-web.xml` itself was `.gitignore`-d). Then I wrote a simple build program which would overwrite `appengine-web.xml` with the appropriate version, then run the build and deployment commands.  This was using the AppEngine SDK.

On my current project I am using the GCloud SDK. Is a better/simpler solution possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the deployment perspective different versions of the same service do not technically share the `appengine-web.xml` file, they each have their own copy of the file reflecting the content of the local file version at the time the respective version was deployed. The very `version` of the service itself can actually be configured in the file, in case you have doubts.

So it's really up to you how you manage the file versioning in the workspace/repository from where you're deploying the service.

You earlier script is one way of doing it.

Another possibility would be to have different versions of the file in different, per-environment branches. A more detailed description can be found in this post (it's about `app.yaml`, it's true, but it's the same general idea): [Google Cloud App Engine app.yaml for multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118879/google-cloud-app-engine-app-yaml-for-multiple-environments/43121949#43121949)

Side note: personally I'd suggest using different applications to implement different environments, not just different versions and/or services, see:

- [Continuous integration/deployment/delivery on Google App Engine, too risky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky/40193364#40193364)
- [Advantages of implementing CI/CD environments at GAE project/app level vs service/module level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43218971/4495081)

Comment: I had tried the one-branch-per-version method, but the issue was that with every merge I had to deal with the conflicting versions of the (for example) `appengine-web.xml` file. How do you reduce friction from this issue?

Comment: The conflicts only show when there are actual changes in the lines that are different in the 2 branches. In my experience the file and particularly those lines don't change that often. Also, in most cases, fixing the conflicts is rather mechanical - I never picked the ones from upstream unless I start using a new GAE feature which I need to configure differently, which again, is rather rare. Personally I prefer this to the risk of the files diverging in the areas that I do want kept in sync, which you'd have to handle manually with 2 different files.